# Using FreeMarker macro in XDocReport

Tags: macros, freemarker, docx, xdocreport

I am trying to use a simple freemarker macro in an XDocReport, but I couldn't find a way to add and call it.

```
<#macro address company>
  <#if company.name??>${company.name}</#if>
  <#if company.address??>${company.address}</#if>
</#macro>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
<@address company=c />
```

where `c` is your company object

Answer (score 0):

You need to add MergeField (which has limit, you can divided in 2 fields) with text:

```
[#macro address company]
  [#if company.name??]${company.name}[/#if]
  [#if company.address??]${company.address}[/#if]
[/#macro]
```

And separated  MergeField to call it (quotes,square brackets are important):

```
"[@address company=c1]"
```